# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:2

Tags: java

I am facing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.... But my String includes more than 2 values

```
  String[] elements = { "Allama Iqbal","born","in","Sailkot"};

 String str = String.join(",", elements); 

           String str = String.join(",", elements);
String[] strArray = new String[] {str};
          if(strArray[2].equals("NNP") ) {
}

The POS are...Allama//NNP
The POS are...Iqbal//NNP
The POS are...,//,
The POS are...born//VBN
The POS are...,//,
The POS are...in//IN
The POS are...,//,
The POS are...Sailkot//NNP
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

Comment: No, if the string array would contain 3 elements, then index 2 would not cause that exception.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
String str = String.join(",", elements);
```

Returns a single string. Therefore this

```
String[] strArray = new String[] {str};
```

only has 1 element

Comment: so what shouuld i do

Comment: You haven't provided any details on what your code is _supposed_ to do so I can't really say. I would update the question to include details on what the task your application is trying to accomplish.